# Find if structures with same values exist in vector array

Tags: c++, stdvector

I want to check if there are structures with the same values in the vector array. May someone explain to me how should I do this?

```
struct mineCoordinate{
int x;
int y;
};

std::vector<mineCoordinate> mines;  // vector array
if(std::find(mines.begin(), mines.end(), mineCoordinate{userInputX,userInputY}) != mines.end()) { 
//do something if true.}
```

As you can see I tried std::find function, and I think it should work (
this is the answer to most of these questions like mine). The only condition was to compare the same objects

Comment: Implement `operator==` or use `std::find_if` passing a predicate as third parameter.

Comment: If you put the coordinates in a `std::array<int,2>` instead of a struct, then your code will work without adding a comparison operator as it's built in for `std::array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems to be missing from your code is a definition of what it means for two of your `mineCoordinate` objects to be equal. If you add this

```
bool operator==(const mineCoordinate& a, const mineCoordinate& b)
{
    return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
}
```

then I think it will work too.

You might have thought that this definition is so obvious that it doesn't need to be explicitly defined, but that is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++20, can you default the `==` operator:

```
struct mineCoordinate 
{
  int x;
  int y;
  bool operator==(const mineCoordinate&) const = default;
};
```